# Easy linear program for Hyperplane separation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am new to linear programming and I'm struggling to formulate a linear program for hyperplane separation:

I came up with two sets of points where the convex hull are not disjoint:

A: {(0,1), (1,2), (2,0)}

B: {(1,1), (3,0), (3,2)}

I want to show that no feasible solution exists by solving a linear program.

---

I formulated the LP with:

- Objective function: max $\alpha^{T}x$
- s.t.

  - $0x_1 + 1x_2 \leq \beta$
  - $1x_1 + 2x_2 \leq \beta$
  - $2x_1 + 0x_2 \leq \beta$
  - $1x_1 + 1x_2 \geq \beta$
  - $3x_1 + 0x_2 \geq \beta$
  - $3x_1 + 2x_2 \geq \beta$
  - $\alpha \neq (0,0)$

Assuming that I formulated the problem correctly, and I wanted to solve this problem by hand using a matrix, would I simply reduce an augmented matrix, such as:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 0 & 1\\
-3 & 0 & -1\\
-3 & -2 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}

..?